# Marketo REST API - what is "dedupeFields" for custom objects?

Tags: marketo

When it comes to creating/updating custom objects, can I use both `dedupeFields` or `lookupField` when pushing the data to Marketo?

What is the difference between the two?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what do you mean under `lookupField`, as there is no such input field described in the API documentation of the [Sync Custom Objects](http://developers.marketo.com/rest-api/endpoint-reference/lead-database-endpoint-reference/#!/Custom_Objects/syncCustomObjectsUsingPOST) endpoint. (That is the endpoint to create or update custom objects.)

In the other hand, you do not need such a standalone lookup field, as with the `input` array you provide the objects you want to create or update, with all their important values. Have a look at the [sample payload](http://developers.marketo.com/rest-api/lead-database/custom-objects/#create_and_update) in the docs.
When `input` is used together with the optional `dedupeBy` and `action` fields, you have full control over which object you want to create or update.

Also, the endpoint expects the name of the dedupe field under `dedupeBy` key, as opposed to `dedupeFields`. So the name is singular; you can provide a single field name use, and it does what you can expect: *if the value in the field for a given record is not unique, an error will be returned for the individual record*.

Comment: Ok so all i need to do is use `dudupeBy` with a value of my dedupe field in Marketo?

Comment: Yes. In case you have an existing record based on that value, that record won't be touched. Otherwise it will be created.

Comment: And that should be the display name or api name of that field?

Comment: I tried both and i keep getting the `Invalid dedupeBy` error although that is my `Dedupe Fields`.
When i use `dedupeFields` it works.

Comment: It should be the REST API name of the field. I guess, you do not get error with `dedupeFields` since it is not checked by Marketo. Which endpoint are you using, the `Sync Custom Objects`? What is the error code you get?

Comment: Yes i'm using the `Sync Custom Objects` endpoint. Getting: `{u'errors': [{u'message': u"Invalid dedupeBy 'negotiationID' value", u'code': u'1003'}], `